# Odoo Link in Chat Doesn't Referring To Actual Domain But Using IP Instead

Tags: odoo, long-polling

Normally, when someone is tagging other user (example in Sales or Purchase representative column), it will create a notification and link of RFQ's or SO's to tagged user.

Our current problem is, when tagged user are opening that link, they are directed to our local IP (192.168.1.95:8069/link-to-document) instead of our domain (example.com/link-to-document). We are using on-premise odoo and nginx as reverse proxy but only accessible using LAN and VPN.

Here is the picture of the problem. I hover the link and it seems directing to our local IP instead of our domain.

[Problem Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k54hbloDPSOIAkHXLNOq20JhNFZCJ_sn/view?usp=sharing)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is your URL freezed in the system parameters of Odoo? Two parameters have to be set right: `web.base.url` and `web.base.url.freeze`. Here is an answer in [Odoo forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/web-base-url-automatic-reset-31937)

Comment: Hi @CZoellner, the problem is already fixed by following suggestion you recommended. thank you so much. How can i mark your answer as solution?

Comment: I can add it as answer first, then you can mark it ;-)

Comment: @CZoellner sure no prob! documentation for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parameters needed:

- `web.base.url` which will be used in lot of features in Odoo like link/url creation for Chatter messages
- `web.base.url.freeze` which will freeze the URL in parameter `web.base.url`